# Raspberry PI 2 undefined reference to

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi2

I have a new RasPi 2, I've installed latest version of Raspbian and all the libraries that I need to compile a project that I'm working on. The libraries were installed from repositories after a "sudo apt-get update" so they should be the latest version.

The compiling of the project works fine, but on linking I get the following errors:

```
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_markup_parse_context_ref'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_variant_new_take_string'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_datalist_id_replace_data'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_spawn_check_exit_status'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `g_slist_copy_deep'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_unix_signal_funcs'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_variant_dict_unref'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_hash_table_get_keys_as_array'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_variant_dict_end'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_source_query_unix_fd'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_datalist_id_dup_data'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_unix_fd_source_funcs'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_str_tokenize_and_fold'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_variant_new_from_bytes'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_variant_check_format_string'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_list_copy_deep'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_variant_get_data_as_bytes'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_variant_dict_ref'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_source_add_unix_fd'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_close'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_variant_dict_new'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_variant_dict_insert_value'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_option_context_parse_strv'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_unix_fd_source_new'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-3.so: undefined reference to `g_variant_parse_error_quark'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgobject-2.0.so: undefined reference to `g_markup_parse_context_unref'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_source_get_ready_time'
/home/andrei/rpi/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined reference to `g_source_set_ready_time'
```

What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to check the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) Stack Exchange.  This type of thing is what they specialize in.

Comment: The order which you place the libraries to link with on the command line is important. If library A depends on library B then A must come before B on the linker command line. Also, all libraries must come after any source or object files.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse to compile the project. The linkage command adds the libraries int the following order: -lgtk-3 -lcurl -lxml2 -ltag -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lpangomm-1.4 -lcairomm-1.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lgtkmm-3.0 -lgstreamer-0.10 -lpthread -lglibmm-2.4 -lgdk-3 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0

Comment: Looks like glibc is missing. Also make sure you include all headers.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error, but the problem was solved by reading libglib-2.0.so.
Because the undefined references shown in your post should be contained in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so, the project must read that library.
It may be a good idea to check the library path or library search path.
Sorry for my poor English.